# Two JARS of different versions without backward-compatibility, same Classloader

Tags: java, jar, classloader, war, libraries

I'm developing a WAR application which have in its lib the **wss4j-1.6.11.jar**. 
I want to develop a new feature that uses the **wss4j-1.5.9.jar**, packing it in a JAR file, and placing it in a directory that is loaded at runtime by the WAR *classloader*. 
I must use the **wss4j-1.6.11.jar** because the WAR application is not of my property, and the **wss4j-1.5.9.jar** because there is a class that is not present in the 1.6.11 version. 
When i put both JARS in the same classloader, it works "fine":

- if I get an instance of a class that is only in **wss4j-1.6.11.jar** (MemoryReplayCache.class), it creates well.
- if I get an instance of a class that is only in **wss4j-1.5.9.jar** (WSDoAllSender.class), it creates well.
- if I get an instance of a class that is **wss4j-1.6.11.jar** and **wss4j-1.5.9.jar** (RequestData.class), it creates an instance of **wss4j-1.5.9.jar** class.

The question is: Should we trust in this implementation? Why, if its always said that classloader ignores duplicate JAR, does it work?

---

The final architecture have got both JARS in the WEB-INF/lib folder. So, the **wss4j-1.6.11.jar** and **wss4j-1.5.9.jar** are loaded at the same way

Comment: It really depends on the order in which you specified the jars on the classpath which class gets loaded if it appears multiple times. But in any case you are begging for strange problems (maybe showing up only after the program ran a while) when you do this. Look for a better solution.

Comment: This sounds like a maintenance nightmare and a recipe for very peculiar container-related issues. If you have to have two jars, I would perhaps develop/deploy two different web apps using different classloaders

Comment: You are both right. It seems I have fallen into JAR-HELL.